# SQLite Database deletes data on app startup, but not app shutdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, entity-framework

I'm building a function app using SQLite with an Insert function. If I start the app using "func start", insert some data, and then I shut down the app via ctrl + c, the data is there and I can query it just fine in VSCode. But when I start the app *again*, that's when all the data gets wiped. Any idea what's causing this? I theorize that the .db file gets recreated everytime, which is why it's wiping the data.

WeatherContext.cs file:

```
public partial class WeatherContext : DbContext
{
    public WeatherContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
    public WeatherContext(DbContextOptions<WeatherContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        
    }

    public DbSet<WeatherDays> WeatherDays{ get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var connString = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=weather.db;PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(conn);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<WeatherDays>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("WeatherDays");
            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("id")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.Property(e => e.date)
                .HasColumnName("date")
                .HasMaxLength(255);
            entity.Property(e => e.temperature)
                .HasColumnName("temperature")
                .HasMaxLength(255);
            entity.Property(e => e.humidity)
                .HasColumnName("humidity")
                .HasMaxLength(255);
        }
        );

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);

}
```

Startup.cs

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(WeatherApp.Startup))]
namespace WeatherApp
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherServices>();
            var connString = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=weather.db;PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<WeatherContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlite(conn)
            );

        }

    }
}
```

I have tried:

- Setting output property of weather.db to copy if newer and always
- Set `;PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;` in the connection string

Comment: Make sure that you are not copying an empty database file on startup every time.

Comment: Hey Mark, any idea how would I do that? I commented out `builder.Services.AddDbContext<WeatherContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlite(conn)
            );`
to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought When I first load the project the first form that loads is frmStart and it checks if the DB Exists code below

```
    private void frmStart_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(dbName))
        {
            btnCreateDB.Visible = true;
            btnAdd.Visible = false;
            Width = 205;
            Height = 115;
            Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            Width = 460;
            Height = 320;
            Refresh();
            btnCreateDB.Visible = false;
            btnAdd.Visible = true;
            tbMessage.Text = "Select Function to Manage Peoples Information";
        }
    }
```

btnCreate calls a frmMakeDB that creates the DB and Tables code below

```
   public partial class frmMakeDB : Form
{
    public string dbName = "APeople.db";
    public frmMakeDB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMakeDB_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        makeDB();
        makeFriendsTable();
        tbMessage.Text = "Database Created";
    }
    public void makeDB()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
            if (!File.Exists(dbName))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
    }

    public void makeFriendsTable()
    {
        // create table FriendsData String for cmd
        string create_table = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FriendsData(
                    FID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    fxFirstName TEXT,
                    fxLastName TEXT,
                    fxInfo TEXT)";

        string dbTable = "FriendsData";
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
            if (!File.Exists(dbTable))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(create_table, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
    }

    private void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        frmStart fST = new frmStart();
        fST.Show();
    }
}
```

Now you know the DB and tables have been created and are ready for the other CRUD function